# How to change the "description" text from an existing windows restore point?

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I just want to change the description of an existing Windows restore point but I dont know how.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sr/systemrestore

```
class SystemRestore
{
  String Description;
  uint32 RestorePointType;
  uint32 EventType;
  uint32 SequenceNumber;
  String CreationTime;
};
```

`RP.Description = "blabalbalat"` should overwrite the description but it just works for this object `RP` but it doesn't change the description in the Windows system (checked it).

```
If WScript.Arguments.Length = 0 Then
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    objShell.ShellExecute "cscript.exe", Chr(34) & _
        WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & " RunAsAdministrator", "", "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
Else
    '--------------
    'Start of code
    'WScript.Echo "This code is ran as an elevated user, ie. 'Administrator'"
    Set RPSet = GetObject("winmgmts:root/default").InstancesOf("SystemRestore")
    For Each RP On RPSet
        RP.Description = "blabalbalat" 'should do its job but doesn't :(
    Next
    '--------------
    'End of code
    '--------------
    'End of UAC workaround code
End If
```

Comment: Is there any way to change the description or is it impossible?

Comment: According to the documentation the property is writable, so it should be possible. However, you don't write the modified object back to the WMI backend. Try running `RP.Put_` after updating the description.